# How to SELECT WHERE LIKE '%@Param%'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Use 'Like' with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587797/how-to-use-like-with-a-parameter)

How do you do this?

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL LIKE % @PARAM %
```

I would like to avoid passing `%value%` in a statement.

Comment: What language are you using? Elaborate?

Comment: Frankly you should avoid doing this type of query altogether. Ther is no way a query like this can use an index. Why do you need a wildcard for the first character? Is youe data model bad , storing things ina comma delimited string perhaps? Or is this something that woudl be better served with using a full-text index? Wanting to do this is a huge database smell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL LIKE '%' + @PARAM + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.........

```
LIKE '%' + @PARAM + '%'
```