# How to use `sp_executesql` with a ´like` and a ´parameter`?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, sql-like

I cant get an sp_executesql working with a very simple statement.

When I do this

```
select * from vwChassisHistory t where t.ChassisNumber like '%1234%'
```

it retuns 214 rows, as I expect

But when I do this

```
exec sp_executesql 
  N'select * from vwChassisHistory t where t.ChassisNumber like ''%@ChassisNumber%'' ',
  N'@ChassisNumber varchar(4)',@ChassisNumber='1234'
```

it returns 0 rows

So I must be making a very stupid mistake here, but I just cannot see it.
How to use `sp_executesql` with a `like` and a `parameter` ?

I lookat at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556506/using-like-in-sp-executesql) but this question is about dynamicly building the statement so it does not help me
Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587797/how-to-use-like-with-a-parameter) does not has an answer for me

**EDIT**
To get the `SqlCommand` to generate the sql as in the accepted answer, I had to modify the code from this

```
string chassisNumber = "1234";

string sql = "select * from vwChassisHistory t ";
string where += "where t.ChassisNumber like '%@ChassisNumber%' ";
```

to this

```
string where = "where t.ChassisNumber like '%' + @ChassisNumber + '%' ";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to separate the `@parameter` and the `%` characters:

```
exec sp_executesql 
  N'SELECT * FROM vwChassisHistory t WHERE (t.ChassisNumber like ''%'' + @ChassisNumber + ''%'')',
  --                                                                   ^                ^
  -- ------------------------------------------------------------------+                |
  -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  N'@ChassisNumber VARCHAR(4)', @ChassisNumber = '1234'
```

In your original query the parameter name becomes part of a string literal and SQL Server ends up searching for the substring `@ChassisNumber`:

```
SELECT * FROM vwChassisHistory t WHERE t.ChassisNumber LIKE '%@ChassisNumber%'
```

The revised query is executed as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM vwChassisHistory t WHERE t.ChassisNumber LIKE '%' + @ChassisNumber + '%'
```

Comment: To elaborate a bit. `t.ChassisNumber like ''%@ChassisNumber%'' ` was effectively looking for the **literal** string `'@ChassisNumber'` in the column `t.ChassisNumber`, not the value of the parameter `@ChassisNumber`.

Comment: The sql statement was generated by an `SqlCommand` I had to modify that code so it generated the correct statement. I put that info as an edit to my answer